# Subtyping Java classes

Tags: java, subtyping

I'm unsure how to subtype if I have a class Instructor and I want class person to be a subtype of it how would I do this?
I've tried class Instructor {} extends Person 
And I receive an error ever time

Comment: Use `public class Instructor extends Person { }`

Comment: `Person` needs to extend `Instructor`. Are some of your instructors not people? O_o

Comment: So it would be the opposite? Extends is like includes?

Comment: Please post your code and the error and you're receiving

Comment: Public abstract class Person {}                                         Class Instructor extends person {}

Comment: Would this make the instructor a person or all persons instructors

Comment: Extends means is a subtype of.

Comment: Corvette is a subtype of car-> Corvette extends car.

Comment: Can you have multiple extends? Such as public abstract class person extends instructor{} && extends student{}

Comment: Do you have a Java book?